Bar report with x axis values ​which is a text field and y axis names in Lookup field
I currently have an object in which there is a Lookup field as well as a text field
I would like to have a report in which each row is a unique lookup name and each column is a unique value in this text field
(it would be necessary to display the number of this text field value in each cell for this lookup)
Here is what I would like:

Here is what I have achieved currently (by grouping the lookup by line and grouping the text field by column but what I see is that the columns are not the text value - In my case i would like having three colums in the report):

Do you have an idea ?
Thank you
